# Issues with .Find Method

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have a large CSV file that was exported by a unix program (this is a different file from the one I asked about on 5/29). It contains several large groups of data stacked vertically and seperated by a one row gap (i.e. A1:J4098 is Sensor1, A4100:J8197 is Sensor2, etc.). The first row of each group is the name of the sensor. I'm trying to write a macro that will search the CSV for a specific sensor name, create a named range that points to that group, and autofilter it (Note: Sensor, Parameter, and Parm are synonymous in our office).

Here is the code I am using:

```
    Set sData = Activeworkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set Generator = ThisWorkbook
    Set Dashboard = Generator.Sheets("Dashboard")

'Set range for .Find
    Set rSensor = sData.Range("J1000000")
    Set rSensor = Range("A18", rSensor.End(xlUp))

'Check if tab already exists and create it if not
    For parm = 3 To 23
        If IsEmpty(Dashboard.Cells(parm, 1)) Then Exit For
        Sensor = Dashboard.Cells(parm, 1)
        Exist = False
        For Each ws In Generator.Worksheets
            If Sensor = ws.Name Then
                Exist = True
                Set NewWS = Generator.Sheets(ws.Name)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next ws

        If Exist = False Then
            Generator.Worksheets("Fband").Copy Before:=Generator.Sheets("Scaled Data")
            Set NewWS = Generator.Worksheets("Fband (2)")
            NewWS.Name = Sensor
        End If

    'Find sensor name in data; set range if found, msgbox if not
' ! Always goes to first sensor in raw data
        With rSensor
            Set c = .Find(Sensor, , xlValues)
            If c Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox ("Parameter Not Found:" & Sensor)
                End
            Else
                Set rData = sData.Cells(c.Row + 1, 1)
                Set rData = Range(rData, rData.End(xlDown))
                Set rData = Range(rData, rData.End(xlToRight))

            'Pull peak amplitude for each frequency band
                For Band = 1 To 136
                    rData.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">" & NewWS.Range("A1").Offset(Band, 1), _
                        Criteria2:="<" & NewWS.Range("A1").Offset(Band, 3)
                    sData.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
                    sData.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B:B"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                        Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                    With sData.AutoFilter.Sort
                        .Header = xlYes
                        .MatchCase = False
                        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                        .Apply
                    End With

                'Replace existing data if greater
                    Set rNew = sData.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 2)
                    If NewWS.Range("A1").Offset(Band, 4).value < rNew.value Then
                        rNew.Copy
                        NewWS.Range("A1").Offset(Band, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    End If

                    rData.AutoFilter Field:=1
                Next Band
            End If
        End With
```

The issue is that the macro returns the same set of data (which happens to be the first set) for every sensor on my list [found in Dashboard.Range("A3:A23")]. I assume the Find function is working because I never get the "Parameter not found" message box, but it's putting the Autofilter on the same group of data every time rather than the group of data immediately following the sensor name.

Comment: Does `Debug.Print rData.Address()` give you what you expect?

Comment: I used `Msgbox (rData.Address())` and it shows that the range is moving with each iteration. But for whatever reason, the AutoFilter is staying put rather than being applied to the new range. Maybe if I turned `AutoFilterMode` off at the end of the loop...

Comment: Yes. That did the trick!